# Why does my method return a null password?

Tags: java, null, passwords

I have two classes: a Generator class and a SystemManagement class. The Generator class, I can generate a password. The SystemManagement class imports Generator (from another package) and includes additional information.

When I make a SystemManagement object and call `getPassword()` on it, I get back `null`. Why is this happening?

Generator:

```
public class Generator {

    private static String password;
    private static Generator instance;

    public String nextPassword() {
        char[] allowedCharacters = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '1', '2', '3', '4',   '5','6'};

        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        StringBuffer password1 = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < password1.length(); i++) {
            password1.append(allowedCharacters[random.nextInt(allowedCharacters.length)]);
        }
        password = password1.toString();
        return password;


    }

    public String currentPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public static void setPassword(String password) {
        Generator.password = password;
    }

    public static Generator getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Generator();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

SystemManagement:

```
public class SystemManagement implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String family;
    private String password;

    public SystemManagement() {

    }

    public SystemManagement(String password) {
        this.password = Generator.getInstance().nextPassword();
    }

    public Students addStudent(String name, String family) {
        Students student = new Students(name, family);
        students.add(student);
        return student;

    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769962/why-am-i-getting-null-on-this-code

Comment: How is that connected to findbugs?

Answer (score 3):

I can spot a couple of problems with your code:

- Your `nextPassword()` method always returns an empty `String` as the password because you iterate over an empty `StringBuilder` with length 0.
- When you create a new `SystemManagement` object with the parameter-less constructor, your `password` is null because you assign nothing to it (unless you use the `setPassword` setter).
- When you create a new `SystemManagement` object with the constructor that takes a `String`, you ignore the parameter and your `password` is empty because `nextPassword()` always returns an empty `String`.

Answer (score 0):

password1.length() is 0 first time, so it never gets filled?

Comment: That would return an empty string, not null.

Answer (score 0):

```
 StringBuffer password1 = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < password1.length(); i++) {
```

I would imagine that that would be `0` for the `length` of the string buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the constructor with no arguments (like `sys = new SystemManagement();`), the new object's `password` member is never set. That only happens if you call the constructor that takes a `String`—which you ignore.

Answer (score 0):

```java
StringBuffer password1 = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < password1.length(); i++) {
    password1.append(allowedCharacters[random.nextInt(allowedCharacters.length)]);
}
```

The for loop will never run as `password1.length()` will be 0 at this time.